# Error Terminal - no abre

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal

me pasa el siguiente problema, al intentar abrir la terminal, desde el menú no abre, y desde Alt+F2 tampoco, al intentar abrir desde LXTerminal sale el siguiente error:

```
desktop:~$ gnome-terminal
# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error al llamar StartSereviceByName para org.gnome.Terminal: Se alcanzó el tiempo de expiración
```

Usando sudo gnome-terminal si la abre como root. Intenté algunas soluciones que encontré en foros sobre este problema, como re instalar el terminal, pero no encontré ninguno que sea exactamente el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstall the GNOME Terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal
```

and you will get missed [org.gnome.Terminal service](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=org.gnome.Terminal).

Comment: Done, but still this 

`desktop:~$ gnome-terminal
# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error al llamar StartSereviceByName para org.gnome.Terminal: Se alcanzó el tiempo de expiración`